# Python: Assign and Eval string to number

Tags: python, variables, dictionary, eval, formula

I'd like to eval a formula by assigning strings to variable and number.
In this example i'd like to have the output 5.

More detail: I'm writing a program, where the user can input a formula and assign those letters in the formula numbers (it's saved in a dict). and then the program should calculate the value of the formula with the given numbers.
My problem is then to 'eval' the formula. see [?] in the following code.

```
formula='a+b'
a='a'
b='b'
dict1={}
dict1[a]=3
dict1[b]=2
[?]
print(eval(formula))
```

I used vars() so far as [?] but now I have a Problem redefining my Variable (e.g. for a changes to 4, vars()[a]=4 isn't changing anything, i still get 5)

```
vars()[a]=dict1[a]
vars()[b]=dict1[b]
```

So is there an alternative to vars() to solve this?

Comment: You need to edit the question to be more clear. What are you trying to achieve, and why? Also, you should not use `dict` as a variable name since it is a python keyword.

Comment: not a python keyword but a built-in. If it was a keyword it would be illegal syntax (small nitpick, but you're right!)

Comment: Change eval to exec("print "+formula) BUT YOU SHOULD NEVER DO THIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give to eval a dictionary to use as global variables:

```
print(eval(formula, dict1))
```